# How to post data or consume a web api using httpclient

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to post data or consume a web api using httpclient. My knowledge with asp.net is limited so anyone pointing me in the right direction will be helpful.
I have a url and l have given it a  generic name localhost. I need to post or consume services from this url.

Here is a sample of my code: This is the model class named Student.

```
namespace Student.Models
{
    public class StudentInfo
    {
        public string id{ get; set; }
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the code controller named StudentController:

```
public void Post([FromBody] string id, string firstname, string lastname, string subject)
{
    Student stu = new Student();
    stu.id = id;
    stu.firstname= firstname;
    stu.lastname = lastname;
    stu.subject = subject;

    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost") };

    // call sync
    var response = client.PostAsync("/api/student/exist", 
    content).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
    }
}
```

I get the error content does not exist in the current context on this line:

```
// call sync
var response = client.PostAsync("/api/membership/exist", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to post **Student** *object* data we need to pass it in the "post request". Therefore, replace `content` by `stu` of .

Also, please try this, add the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` for `PostAsJsonAcync` and add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting

```
// call sync
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/student/exist", stu).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just getting a compiler error because you are trying to use a variable, `content`, that you haven't declared anywhere else in your code. I'm guessing that you made a simple mistake, and the line should read:

`var response = client.PostAsync("/api/student/exist", stu).Result;`

Answer (score 0):

Also don't block async code. Make the action return a task:

```
public async Task Post([FromBody] string id, string firstname, string lastname, string subject)
```

and change your request to:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/student/exist", stu);
```